# Adding a weight/score to a record

Tags: sql

I have a table of customers with mailing addresses. I'm trying to add a "weight" to each customer based on whether they share that address with other customers, as follows:

```
UPDATE
   CT 
SET
   Household_Weight = Cnt 
FROM
   CT 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            Mail_Address,
            COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
         FROM
            CT 
         GROUP BY
            Mail_Address
      )
```

Any advice?

Comment: Whey you group by - you always have a level break key and a total. You can't set 1 column to 2

Comment: Tag your question with he database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a subquery?

```
update ct
    set Household_Weight = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM CT CT2 WHERE ct2.Mail_Address = ct.Mail_Address);
```

Not all databases support `FROM` in `UPDATE`.

Comment: Wording of question is unclear. Who knows if Mail_Address even exists on ct! ;-)